# Nginx: redirect HTTPS site to www HTTPS, need certificate?

Tags: nginx, https

I have a certificate for `example.com` and `www.example.com` and the following config:

```
server {
    listen              443 ssl;
    listen              [::]:443 ssl;
    server_name         example.com;
    return              301 https://www.example.com$request_uri;
}
```

I am trying to redirect to `www.example.com` and it works when I visit `https://example.com`. I get redirected successfully. But I don't understand why it works. The 301 redirect should be happening over SSL, but I did not specify the certificate. How could it work?

Also, what would be the recommended way to do that? Is it just to add the certificate in the block above?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you need a certificate for the https:// site to redirect to https://www site. In general the easiest way is to get a certificate that covers both the www and non-www and use that in both server configurations. Let's Encrypt does this no problem.

**Why does your configuration work?**

I have no idea why your configuration above works, with no certificate specified. As far as I know It shouldn't.

I put your config into my Nginx instance on AWS, slightly tweaked as follows

```
server {
  listen              443 ssl;
  listen              [::]:443 ssl;
  server_name         example2.com;
  return              301 https://www.example2.com$request_uri;
}

server {
  listen              443 ssl;
  listen              [::]:443 ssl;
  server_name         www.example2.com;

  root /var/www/folder;
}
```

I added the following to my /etc/hosts

```
11.0.1.10 example2.com www.example2.com
```

When I did a wget this is what I got

```
wget https://www.example2.com
--2017-07-29 08:07:17--  https://www.example2.com/
Resolving www.example2.com (www.example2.com)... 11.0.1.10
Connecting to www.example2.com (www.example2.com)|11.0.1.10|:443...     connected.
Unable to establish SSL connection.
```

You can see that it can connect to the server, but can't establish an SSL connection. When I use curl I get a different response, but it doesn't work.

```
curl https://www.example2.com
curl: (35) Encountered end of file
```

Based on this I think there's something missing from what you've told us.

**Here's how it should be**

This shows how Nginx should be configured.

```
# Main website, https www
server {
  server_name www.example.com;
  listen 443 ssl http2; # http2 is optional
  ssl_certificate /path/to/fullchain;
  ssl_certificate_key /path/to/privkey;

  # locations etc
}

# forward https non-www to www
server {
  server_name example.com;
  listen 443 ssl;
  ssl_certificate /path/to/fullchain;
  ssl_certificate_key /path/to/privkey;

  return 301 https://www.example.com$request_uri;
}    

# Forward http to https
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  example.com www.example.com;
    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log main buffer=128k flush=1m if=$log_ua;
    return       301 https://example.com$request_uri;
}
```

Comment: But why does it work anyway without the certificate? Even in the answer you linked, you don't have the certificate for the https redirect.

Comment: The linked answer says the ssl config is needed but doesn't provide it. I'll edit my question to add a little more, in a few minute after I've done a test.

Comment: I can't find the place where it says the ssl config is needed but not provided in the linked answer.

Comment: I've removed the linked answer because it seems to be distracting you. I've expanded my answer above to cover what the linked question said, but I've spelled things out explicitly.

Comment: My configuration worked because the `https://www` server (not shown in my question) had the default_server option in the listen directive. If the ssl_certificate is not defined in the `https://example.com` server block, it will check in the default server.